# EF core is using LEFT JOIN instead of inner join

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, left-join, inner-join

I was using `ToQueryString` of EF Core and was faced with this use case that looks strange to me:

I have a `Backpack` table with this data:

[image: full backpack table]

As you can see, three records have students and three of them haven't. So I am creating this query:

```cs
var query = context.Set<Backpack>()
    .Where(s => s.Student != null)
    .Select(s => s.Student.Name);
```

And then getting SQL-query using `ToQueryString`:

```cs
var sql = query.ToQueryString();
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    [s].[Name]
FROM
    [Backpack] AS [b]
    LEFT JOIN [Student] AS [s] ON [b].[StudentId] = [s].[Id]
WHERE
    [s].[Id] IS NOT NULL
```

The query is returning the expected result, but as you can see it is using `LEFT JOIN` and then adding the condition: `WHERE [s].[Id] IS NOT NULL`

Why it is not using INNER JOIN instead of that? Like:

```sql
SELECT
    [s].[Name]
FROM
    [Backpack] AS [b]
    INNER JOIN [Student] AS [s] ON [b].[StudentId] = [s].[Id]
```

Is it something standard way of EF core SQL translation, or `LEFT JOIN` is more performant or it is just a bug or something else?

Model configuration:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data source=localhost;integrated security=True;Database=InnerTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var student = modelBuilder.Entity<Student>();
            student.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            var backpack = modelBuilder.Entity<Backpack>();
            backpack.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            backpack.HasOne(x => x.Student).WithMany(s => s.Backpacks).HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId);
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Backpack> Backpacks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Backpack
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public Guid? StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

EF Core version: 6.0.9

SQL Server version: 15.0.2000.5

Comment: **Exactly** what versions of .NET, EF Core and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Also, please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements for your `Backpack` and `Student` tables (use "SSMS > Your-Database > Tables > $table > Script as > Create to...")

Comment: `Where(s => s.Student != null)` <-- This line is responsible for the `WHERE [s].[Id] IS NOT NULL` clause.

Comment: @Dai In this query INNER JOIN will be a good solution. If we use INNER join we don't need to do  WHERE [s].[Id] IS NOT NULL. However, LEFT JOIN + WHERE [s].[Id] IS NOT NULL will get the same result

Comment: Not required navigation will always result into LEFT JOIN. If you need INNER JOIN, you have to do JOIN explicitly.

Comment: EF always tries to return all objects in the query root (i.e. the DbSet at the start of the query), hence the outer join. You can get the desired effect by something like `Students.Where(s => s.Backpacks.Any()).Select(s => s.Name)`.

Comment: @GertArnold, it is much more slower query, even there is LEFT JOIN. In SQL Server there are almost no difference in speed between INNER and LEF JOIN.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I guess OP should evaluate the difference. The difference may not be significant. But it's a way to do it without manual joins, just using navigation properties, which may be preferred. BTW, I have experienced huge performance differences between INNER and OUTER joins.